# Registrating with only @csus.edu email

Tags: android

I am building a registration page for a carpool app and I would like to only have a school email address used in the registration. How to input @csus.edu email into Android Studio app?

Currently I have:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Email"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etEmail"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't let them type it, and don't make it appear in the input box.
Something like:

```
Name: [text box] @csus.edu
```

so in this case, "Name:" and "@csus.edu" are both labels.

Comment: How would I code it in Android Studio? Currently, I have 

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

Comment: Why don't you do a TextView, EditText, then another TextView?

Comment: Do you mean I need another text field for @csus.edu part?

Comment: Do you mean additional TextView is for the @csus.edu part because we already have one for the email.

Comment: In my answer, there are 3 "objects".  Think about how you can map it to code elements.

Answer (score 0):

Client side validation. Just Substring whatever they enter

`String end = EmailInput.substring(EmailInput.length() - 9, EmailInput.length());
boolean isValid = end.equals("@csus.edu);`

That being said, I also agree with ergonaut in that save the user the time and trouble by not giving the option to enter a wrong email.